# Don't work directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am only start study angular and want understand why my code doesn't work. 
Code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['appModule']).config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');});

var appModule = angular.module('appModule', []);
appModule.directive('name', function(){
    return{
        restrict   : 'E',        
        scope      : {},      
        //transclude : true,      // it has HTML content
        link       : function(scope, element, attrs, controllers){
            scope.fullName = attrs.first + " " + attrs.second
        },
        tempalte   : '<h1>[[ fullName ]]</h1>'
    }
});
```

In my html

```
<name data-first="Jack" data-second="Nollan"></name>
<name data-first="Chris" data-second="John"></name>
```

I include angular and my scripts. Angular work, i test. 
My code in result print nothing ( Can anybody help me?

P.S.
If you can explain what do this `transclude : true,` i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, template is spelt incorrectly in the directive and secondly, in the HTML you need to use `{{ fullName }}` instead of `[[ fullName ]]`

Your directive should be:

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', []);
appModule.directive('name', function(){
  return {
      restrict   : 'E',        
      scope      : {},      
      //transclude : true,      // it has HTML content
      link       : function(scope, element, attrs, controllers){
          scope.fullName = attrs.first + " " + attrs.second
      },
      template   : '<h1>{{ fullName }}</h1>'
  }
});
```

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uWC2hYoZBdJmqEjDmmJb?p=preview)

**Transclude:**
Using transclude allows you to inject HTML into your directive. In the directive itself you can place the `ng-transclude` directive and Angular will replace this with the HTML you want to inject.

In your example if you wanted to display the text 'says hello' after the name of the person you could change your directive to this:

```
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', []);
appModule.directive('name', function(){
return{
    restrict   : 'E',        
    scope      : {},      
    transclude : true,      // it has HTML content
    link       : function(scope, element, attrs, controllers){
        scope.fullName = attrs.first + " " + attrs.second
    },
    template   : '<h1>{{ fullName }} <ng-transclude></ng-transclude></h1>'
}
});
```

In your HTML you can then enter the text in the `<name />` element like so:

```
<name first="Jack" second="Nollan"> says Hello</name>
```

Angular will then insert the text 'says Hello' wherever you have placed the `ng-transclude` directive in your directive template. Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LV60byFUgqTiss1ITZS1?p=preview) showing this.

Comment: I have added a plnkr to the answer showing this working

Comment: i saw, but in my code it still doesn't work. 
If you can explain what do this transclude : true, i will be very grateful.

Comment: @keithm you could override $interpolation symbols

Comment: I have added a description of how transclude works (albeit a not very useful example)